# BigQuery UTC hardcoded removal

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some time stamp column which have data like-2022-12-02 10:30:35 AM UTC
I want to remove UTC from this data. This table is in big query

Comment: CAST(col AS STRING FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking for free help to solve **your** problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be using [format_timestamp()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp). See approach below:

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select parse_timestamp("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p %Z",'2022-12-02 10:30:35 AM UTC') as test_time
)

select 
  format_timestamp("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p",test_time) as new_format 
from sample_data
```